# the requested database is not defined in configuration while calling CreateDatabase method

Tags: c#, wcf, enterprise-library

I'm trying to use Enterprise Library to create database connection and it gives the error "the requested database is not defined in configuration"

I have 2 config files. One is for appSettings and the other is for connection string. We use a custom framework to take the config values from an external path in the system, eg.

C:\application\environments\dev\environments.config
C:\application\environments\dev\connections.config

The environment.config has a connectionString element which has the configSource="connections.config".

When I run the application, I'm able to get all the appSetting from the environments.config, but when I try to call the DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase("dbConnection"), it throws the error. I'm not sure if I'm missing something or not. I read through many articles and couldn't find the exact problem.

I use Enterprise Library Common and Data dll and their version is 3.1.1.0. My .NET framework is 4.0.

Can anybody please provide me some idea to make this work?

Do I need to make any setting changes in machine.config?